# uninitialized constant Rails (NameError) in Rails 3.213

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, nameerror

When I attempt to visit the rails site I am working or attempt to run the rake I get the following error

```
uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)
 /path/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
 /path/config/environment.rb:11:in `require'
 /path/config/environment.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
```

Here is line 4 of my boot file

```
Rails.root  = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/.." unless defined?(Rails.root)
```

and line 11 of my enviroment file
 `require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')`

The error seems to be that that when I call Rails.root, it perceives Rails to somehow be uninitialized. Any ideas?

If any more info is needed let me know. Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try updating `rubygems` with `gem update --system`. 
Looks like there were some issues and that they were fixed in recent versions.

If not then it works after adding:

```
gem install bundler
```

and after adding:

```
gem 'bundler'
```

in line 2 in config/boot.rb (just after `require 'rubygems'`)

Please let me know

Comment: Running 'gem update --system' returned 'Latest version currently installed. Aborting.' Did you mean to add 'gem install bundler' and 'gem 'bundler'' in the second line, or after the 'require 'rubygems' line which is later?

Comment: Yes, please try after adding it.

Comment: delete GEM.lock file, then run bundler install

Comment: I think it's bundler version problem.

Comment: My bundler is at 1.3.5, the current version

Comment: Trying to trace out the problem, will get back to you soon.